# Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

Tags: java, web-services, rest, io, spring-boot

Hi Guys as  this is my controller class when i run this application in postman adds-on its displaying status 200 ok.but file not reading how can i pass filename with extention as a string parameter in method? what iam missing ur assistance is highly appreciable and a knowledgeable

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable String name) {
    try {
        File inputFile = fileSystemHandler.read(name);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
         headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, "" + inputFile.length());
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename= " + name);
        InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // return data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is my File system handler class

```
public File read(String name) {
    File inputFile = null;
    try {
        inputFile = new File(env.getProperty("file.Path") + name);
        return inputFile;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileSystemHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return inputFile;
}
```

Comment: **Never** do such things:  } catch (Exception ex) {
        // return data;
    }. The Minimum is logging the exception.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you,yahooo It's working,your assistance is highly appreciable and a knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question reads unclear, but I'm assuming that you are are requesting something like "readme.txt" but inside the request you are getting plain "readme" when checking filename. This is because spring tries to use the .txt at end of path to determine the content type of the response. You need to either disable that behaviour or use a **trailing slash** at end of your request (http://localhost:8080/file/readme.txt/).

To disable in spring-boot you would do, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class MvcConfig extends EnableWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        super.configurePathMatch(configurer);
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, Thank you for your assistance is highly appreciable and a knowledgeable.